# bash/sh cron not writing

Tags: bash, if-statement, cron, sh

Can anyone see what I have done wrong here? This is a simpler piece of my own code that works just fine. I have never tested it on sh though. Perhaps something just isn't working on sh? The if statement opens cron and looks for an identical line before writing. This prevents duplicates.

```
if [ "`crontab -l | grep $SCRIPT`" \> " " ]; then
  (crontab -l ; echo "*/10 * * * * cd /etc/myscript/sh && ./start.sh") | crontab -
fi
```

It never writes anything to cron. The command inside the if statement works 100% by itself. Somehow the if statement is broken.

Here is another way of looking at it:

```
if [ "`crontab -l | grep start.sh`" \> " " ]; then
  (crontab -l ; echo "*/10 * * * * cd /etc/myscript/sh && ./start.sh") | crontab -
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement works in the wrong direction: the`then` clause is executed only if the script is already installed.  Also, it can be simplified:

```
if ! crontab -l | grep -q start.sh; then
```

This works because `grep` sets a proper exit code.